# Rectangle division into shapes and connecting adjacent shapes with non-intersecting lines

Tags: geometry, rectangles, centroid

Rectangle is divided into several non-convex shapes. Adjacent shape's centroids are connected with straight lines.

For example (here centroids are approximate):

[image]

Could it be that some of those line cross each other?

Comment: Well, already, the line connecting the red and yellow centroids cross the line connecting the green and blue centroids. You need to be more specific about your question.

Comment: @VictorLiu Red and yellow shapes are not adjacent. I want to know about lines connecting adjacent shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|  +--+--+  |
|  |     |  |
|  +-----+  |
|  |     |  |
|  +--+--+  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: As I can deduce, answer is yes, it is possible.